# Proper input data for DBSCAN from http://scikit-learn.org

Tags: python, gis, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I found the example confusing in http://scikit-learn.org for the DBSCAN algorithm. I have a list of latitude and longitudes and was curious how to prepare the input for the the DBSCAN algorithm here.

Comment: I recommend using ELKI, which can use Geodetic distance and R*-tree indexes at the same time, to substantially speed up the algorithm.

Comment: Is ELKI implemented in python?

Comment: No. But it's the only tool I know which has the capability of accelerating DBSCAN with geodetic distance.

Comment: Just provided an answer to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816084/clustering-longitude-and-latitude-gps-data/39937326#39937326